# Dashboard for monitoring the results of an iterative program

Tags: python, linux, dashboard

I run a Python code in which an iterative process is done. Every few minutes an iteration is performed and the results are stored in a file. Currently, after each iteration I have to run another Python script to plot the recent results to monitor the progress. I want to have a dashboard which plots the recent results whenever the results file is updated.

Answer (score 3):

It's not entirely clear what your question is, but it sounds like you want to monitor the output file for changes and plot them when the file is changed.

If you're using Linux (as the tag suggests), then I'd suggest using `inotify`, which is a Linux API allows you to monitor filesystem events (like file writes!).

There is a Python wrapper around this, also named `inotify`: https://pypi.org/project/inotify/. You should be able to add a watch on your log file and run your plotting function when it's modified (perhaps by watching for the `IN_CLOSE_WRITE` event).